# How to automatically copy up the value of selected option of dropdown list into a text. Using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Form input value based on option value selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802235/form-input-value-based-on-option-value-selected)

I have a dropdown list. I want that whenever I select a value from the dropdown, the selected value is automatically copied into a text box in the same form. I would like to make use of jQuery and not simply other, plain Javascript methods.

The code for the form is:

```
<s:form action="okadddqs" method="post" cssClass="text">
    <s:select label="Correct Option :" 
        id="opc"
        name="opc"       
        list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{'One':'One', 'Two':'Two','Three':'Three','Four':'Four','Five':'Five'}"/>
    <s:textfield label="Choosed Option" id="cname" name="cname"/>
    <s:submit value="Submit now"/>
```

I wnat `cname` to be filled automatically with the selected value of `opc`. How do I implement this?

Comment: I have edited the question with my code. Can someone help me out now. I am waiting..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form input value based on option value selected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7802235/). Note that jQuery *is* Javascript. "Plz give teh codez" type questions are generally frowned upon, as is impatience. Both denote an attitude of entitlement.

Comment: Can some one help me on this problem as well..? thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#opc").change(function(){
        $("#cname").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XVDH2/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I am not for sure on the names or other selectors of your elements, so here is a generic means of achieving what you are looking for:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var el = $(this);

  el.closest('form').find('input[type=text]').val( el.val() );

});
```

Comment: I have edited the question with the code of form in jsp page.
I am very very new to jquery. So can u please post the exact full code inside the <script> </script> tag. Actually i am not getting what what this code is doing so m not able to modify according to my needs. SO please post the whole script code. Thanks.

Comment: Can u please post the modified code according to the ids and selectors as per the form asks. I have edited the question with the code of he form. Please do this. coz i am new to jquery. and i am not able to modify the code. waiting for the help...