# Button wont open mailto:address based off of dropdown from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database with the table storeconst. In this table I have a column called Store and GenManageEmail. My drop down successfully populates the list of stores in the database. However my send button doesn't dynamically change to the appropriate email and the button doesn't click to a mailto:email@domain.com link.

```
<?php
require ("dbconnect.php");
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
?>

<div class="label">Select Store:</div>

<select name="stores">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `storeconst` ORDER BY `Store` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['GenManageEmail']."}'>".$d['Store']."</option>";
}
?>
  </select> 
<button name="send" value=mailto:.$d['GenManageEmail']. type="submit">Send</button>
```

So for example if they select Philadelphia as the store, then the send button should reflect phillymanager@domain.com. If they select Los Angeles its should reflect losangelesmanager@domain.com
The column GenManageEmail has all the emails. Here is a picture to reference to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgUaU.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Well, no. To dynamically change the content on the client, you'll need some javascript - you can't do it within PHP, as the HTML you're generating is created on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt this for you.  Not tested but should work.  The PHP below will handle the email sending instead of directly from the form.  Basically the html form will collect the data, and send it back to this page, where the email will send to the email you select, and it will send the store name you select.

I think this is what you want.. let me know if you want any changes done and if it works.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("YOUR HOST ADDRESS","YOUR USERNAME","YOUR PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("YOUR DB NAME");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// // COLLECT FORM INFO AND SEND EMAIL // //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (isset ($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $store = $_POST['store'];

    $subject = '';  // Set the subject text here
    $message = $store; // The store you selected
    $to = $email; // The email you selected
    $type = 'HTML'; // Ignore this
    $charset = 'utf-8'; // Ignore this
    $mail     = 'Store Info'; // From Address
    $uniqid   = md5(uniqid(time())); // Ignore this
    $headers  = 'From: '.$mail."\n"; // Ignore this

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Your mail being sent!

    print 'Success! You have sent '.$store.' to '.$email.'!'; // Your success msg! Set this to anything.  A lot of options here.
    exit();  
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// // GET DATA FROM SQL DB // //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$genManSelector = ''; //Initialize dynamic dropdown selection list variable for email list
$storeSelector = ''; //Initialize dynamic dropdown selection list variable for store list
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT GenManageEmail, Store FROM storeconst ORDER BY Store ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $GenManageEmail = $row["GenManageEmail"];
    $getStore = $row["Store"];
    $genManSelector .= '<option value="'.$GenManageEmail.'">'.$GenManageEmail.'</option>';
    $storeSelector .= '<option value="'.$getStore.'">'.$getStore.'</option>';
    //Adove is your dynamic dropdown selection lists.  All stores and 
    //emails that are in your database will be available for selection.
}
?>
```

HTML form below, set the form action to your page url.

```
<form action="thisPage.php" method="post">
   Select Email:<br>
   <select name="email">
      <?php print $storeSelector ?>
   </select><br>  
   Select Store:<br>
   <select name="store">
      <?php print $storeSelector ?>
   </select><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Send to Manager">
</form>
```

This is really basic and should really be dressed up

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't open outlook with the email address.

Comment: It's looking like I need some JS to change the value. After I make a selection of a store the value stays simply "mailto:"

Comment: I have tried using Javascript. I am a newbie when it comes to JS. Can you help?

Comment: I wrote up what i think may be a solution to your problem.  Without the use of javascript.  Check my edit.  This writeup is allowing for a single email address to send to, which is i think what you want??  If you want to be able to select which email as well, let me know.

Comment: This works 95% the only issue is that when the page loads it automatically selects the first store and no matter what I change it still sends to the same email. Thank you so much this is great progress!

Comment: It is set to grab the first email in the database.  Do you want it to send to a random email? Or do you want to be able to select an email?  also, can i get a vote up if you like this answer?  thanks hyperj123

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote up??? And the store corresponds to the a managers email. So if I select philly it goes to phillymanager@domain.com or if i select new york it goes to newyorkmanager@domain.com. The send email button changes based on what store is being actively selected from the drop down. Much appreciated

Comment: Try this.  I rebuilt the code for you and I think you may like it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've missed the quotes in the `value` param.

That will address your issue with the button not sending you to a mail client.

**However..**

Since PHP is processed on the server, trying to change the email by substituting in `$d['GenManageEmail']` on the page won't work. It's a **hypertext-preprocessor**.

This may help you understand: view the source of the page and notice how the button's `value` param remains `mailto:$d['GenManageEmail']`.

I believe what you're trying to do is have the browser send the person to the selected email. For this, you will need JavaScript.

Comment: Can you link me or post a JS script that would change the button value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802235/form-input-value-based-on-option-value-selected Take a look at this :)

Comment: From this script it looks like I have to type in every email address for the options. Are there any other JS's that I could reference to?

Comment: You don't. You can do another `while` loop to write out the JavaScript. Keep in mind, you can manipulate JavaScript with PHP. It's just like manipulating HTML with it.

Comment: Okay I'm a bit of a newbie. Can you type something up for me?