# Set Form Input Attribute by Selected Option Attribute

Tags: javascript, forms

My goal is to add the value and attribute(s) of the options in a select field to an input element.

The options are generated dynamically - it would be feasible for me to give each a unique ID if that would help divine a solution.

I have the following code ( [here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jryven/xL1uu0za/) ):

HTML

```
<select size="3" width="220" style="width:220px" id="select_trainer" multiple="yes"> 
    <option value="1" name="unique-code-1" id="unique-id-1">Jillian</option>
    <option value="2" name="unique-code-2" id="unique-id-2">James</option>
    <option value="3" name="unique-code-3" id="unique-id-3">Jean</option>
</select>
<input value="" name="" id="save_select_profile" checked="checked"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('select_trainer').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('save_select_profile').value = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('save_select_profile').setAttribute('name', event.target.name);
}
```

The javascript (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802235/form-input-value-based-on-option-value-selected) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802235/form-input-value-based-on-option-value-selected)) does a great job of setting the value of the input field to match the option that is selected.

But my addition - `document.getElementById('save_select_profile').setAttribute('name', event.target.name);` - does not set the selected-option name attribute to the input.

I found that if the `<select>` element has a `name` value set, that value is added to input instead.

How do I pass the selected, child element name value to the `input` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event.target will return the whole select element, not the nested option tag, which stores the name that you're trying to set. To get the selected option, you need to do:

```
event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex]
```

Then to get that selected option's name, you do:

```
event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
```

Then you set the name, the way you were doing it with your setAttribute function.

[Here is a working CodePen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/bEMVKP)

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL1uu0za/8/)**

Try to target the selected option by index using `selectedIndex` then get attribute name using `getAttribute` function.

```
document.getElementById('select_trainer').onchange = function () {
  var my_select = event.target;
  var option_name = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');

  document.getElementById('save_select_profile').value = my_select.value;
  document.getElementById('save_select_profile').setAttribute('name', option_name);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
document.getElementById('select_trainer').onchange = function () {
  var my_select = event.target;
  var option_name = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');

  document.getElementById('save_select_profile').value = my_select.value;
  document.getElementById('save_select_profile').setAttribute('name', option_name);
  
  document.getElementById('test').value = document.getElementById('save_select_profile').getAttribute('name');
}
```

```html
<select name='55' size="3" width="220" style="width:220px" id="select_trainer" multiple="yes"> 

<option value="1" name="unique-code-1" id="unique-id-1">Jillian</option>
<option value="2" name="unique-code-2" id="unique-id-2">Jillian</option>
<option value="3" name="unique-code-3" id="unique-id-3">Jillian</option>

</select>
<br>    
<input value="" name="null" id="save_select_profile" checked="checked"/>
<br>
<input type='text' id="test"/>
```

Comment: This answer words, I selected the other answer because the work could be done in fewer lines.

Comment: You're welcome @JamesRyvenValeii, I prefers readability of code more than shortcuts for the futur readers and to reach most users levels, that why I separated the code like this. (happy coding)